# How similar are pullbacks to products?

Tags: category-theory

Please excuse me if this is a trivial question.

Let $f:A\to B$ and $g:C\to B$ be morphisms in a category and consider their pullback. I have seen books that say $projections$ for the morphisms $A\times_B C\to A$ and $A\times_B C\to C$, which resembles the notation for the product: I would like to understand how much pullbacks behave like products.

The specific question I have in mind is this: Suppose I have three morphisms with the same codomain, $f:A\to B$, $g:C\to B$ and $h:D\to B$. We can form the pullback $A\times_B C\times_B D$ (universality says it doesn't matter how) and projections $p_{AC}:A\times_B C\times_B D\to A\times_B C$, $p_{AD}:A\times_B C\times_B D\to A\times_B D$ and $p_{CD}:A\times_B C\times_B D\to C\times_B D$.
We also have further projections $p_A:A\times_B C\to A$ and $p_C:A\times_B C\to C$ in the first case and so on, two for each pullback.

My question is this: consider the two composites (each composite consisting of two projections) that begin from $A\times_B C\times_B D$ and end at one of the objects, say $A$. (So in this case, you can reach $A$ either by going through $A\times_B C$ or through $A\times_B D$.) What is the relation between these two composites? If $\times_B$ was $\times$, then they would have to be equal by universality.

Thanks!

Comment: *"We can form..."* Not necessarily. There exist many categories where there do not exist pullbacks of an arbitrary pair of morphisms.

Comment: Yes, of course. I meant in a suitable setup. I am just not comfortable with the manipulation of pullbacks, given their existence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pullback of two morphisms $f: A\to B$ and $g: C\to B$ in a category ${\mathscr C}$ is, if it exists, the product in the *overcategory* (or *slice category*) ${\mathscr C}/B$, the latter being the category whose objects are morphisms $X\to B$ in ${\mathscr C}$, and whose morphisms $(X\to B)\to (Y\to B)$ are the morphisms $X\to Y$ in ${\mathscr C}$ such that $X\to Y\to B=X\to B$.

Hence, anything you know about products formally applies to pullbacks as well.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I think in English we always call the overcategory a "[slice category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_category#Slice_category)".

Comment: Hey, @hanno, thanks! Where can I read more about this? I have not seen this mentioned anywhere, I had no idea about this relationship.

Comment: @BenBarrows: I don't know a source that details particularly on this description of the pullback, but I'm sure you'll be able to write out the details yourself.

Comment: @MJD: I added it. There doesn't seem to be a standard terminology here.

Comment: @MJD I've seen both. For example in Hirschhorn's book (random example) they're called overcategories. (I find it easier for recalling which is which too.)